# Set a default return value for a Postgres function

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, if-statement, plpgsql

I have the following function in Postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION point_total(user_id integer, gametime date)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$BODY$
SELECT sum(points) AS result
  FROM picks
 WHERE user_id = $1
   AND picks.gametime > $2
   AND points IS NOT NULL;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

It works correctly, but when a user starts out and has no points, it very reasonably returns NULL. How can I modify it so that it returns 0 instead.

Changing the body of the function to that below results in an "ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF".

```
SELECT sum(points) AS result
  FROM picks
 WHERE user_id = $1
   AND picks.gametime > $2
   AND points IS NOT NULL;

IF result IS NULL
   SELECT 0 AS result;
END;
```

Comment: May I inquire the version of PostgreSQL in use? I guess 8.4?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change the language from `sql`to `plpgsql` if you want to use the procedural features of PL/pgSQL. The function body changes, too.

Be aware that **all parameter names are visible in the function body**, including all levels of SQL statements. If you create a naming conflict, you may need to table-qualify column names like this: `table.col`, to avoid confusion. Since you refer to function parameters by positional reference (`$n`) anyway, I just removed parameter names to make it work.

Finally, `THEN` was missing in the `IF` statement - the **immediate cause of the error message**.

One could use [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to substitute for `NULL` values. But that only works if there is at least one resulting row. `COALESCE` can't fix "no row" it can only replace actual `NULL` values.

There are several ways to cover all `NULL` cases. In **plpgsql functions**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION point_total(integer, date, OUT result bigint)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$func$
BEGIN

SELECT sum(p.points)          -- COALESCE would make sense ...
INTO   result
FROM   picks p
WHERE  p.user_id = $1
AND    p.gametime > $2
AND    p.points IS NOT NULL;  -- ... if NULL values were not ruled out

IF NOT FOUND THEN             -- If no row was found ...
   result := 0;               -- ... set to 0 explicitly
END IF;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or you can enclose the whole query in a `COALESCE` expression in an outer `SELECT`. "No row" from the inner `SELECT` results in a `NULL` in the expression. Work as plain SQL, or you can wrap it in an **sql function**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION point_total(integer, date)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$func$
SELECT COALESCE(
  (SELECT sum(p.points)
   FROM   picks p
   WHERE  p.user_id = $1
   AND    p.gametime > $2
   -- AND    p.points IS NOT NULL  -- redundant here
  ), 0)
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Related answer:

- [How to display a default value when no match found in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200462/how-to-display-a-default-value-when-no-match-found-in-a-query/8200473#8200473)

#### Concerning naming conflicts

One problem was the naming conflict most likely. There have been major changes in **version 9.0**. I quote the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/release-9-0.html):

> E.8.2.5. PL/pgSQL
>
> PL/pgSQL now throws an error if a variable name conflicts with a
> column name used in a query (Tom Lane)

Later versions have refined the behavior. In obvious spots the right alternative is picked automatically. Reduces the potential for conflicts, but it's still there. The advice still applies in Postgres 9.3.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer Erwin, I should probably have stated in the original question that this was on 9.x

Comment: In PostgreSQL the first digit after the dot is relevant to distinguish major releases. 9.1 has many improvements over 9.0, for instance.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter the default parameter makes it so useful