# How to display a default value when no match found in a query?

Tags: sql, oracle, coalesce

I want to display a default message when there is no data obtained from a query.

For example
Let us take a query

> select empname from employee where id = 100

If  no data matches this search i want to get `Unavailable` as a result or the required result should display.

So how should i write a SQL query to achieve this.

I am using Oracle 10g.

Comment: You really should just return `null` and let your calling application decide how it will behave when encountering `db_null` instead of doing it in your DB.

Comment: @Seph : Thanks for the tip, if i return null in the calling application i have to replace the null with the a default message. So instead of the if i an trying to do it the query itself.

Comment: I had already had thought of all these scenario's and then only moved the IF() to SQL as the behavior was be the same in both the places

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT empname FROM employee WHERE id = 100), 'Unavailable')
FROM   DUAL;
```

You have to wrap the `SELECT` into another `SELECT` or no row will be returned. And where there is no row, there cannot be a value.