# Optimize a max() aggregate that works for "no rows", too

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.2, coalesce, postgresql-performance

I have a query that I am trying to optimize for PostgreSQL 9.2:

```
select coalesce(max(id),0) as m from tbl
```

It takes for forever to run, so I figured I could rewrite it as

```
select id from tbl order by id desc limit 1
```

except it needs to return `0` if there are no rows in the table. I've tried a few combinations of case statements, but they don't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Plan for an empty table:

```
Aggregate (cost=11.25..11.26 rows=1 width=4)
 -> Seq Scan on tbl (cost=0.00..11.00 rows=100 width=4)
```

The cost is 58k with a table with 1,190,000 rows, same execution plan though.

Comment: What is `a m` ? Typo? should it be `select coalesce(max(id),0) AS m from tbl`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name id is the primary key

This is the plan for an empty table

"Aggregate  (cost=11.25..11.26 rows=1 width=4)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..11.00 rows=100 width=4)"
The cost is 58k with a table with 1,190,000 rows, same execution plan though

Comment: This is how I'd expect the plan to look like: http://explain.depesz.com/s/hp8 (the table has 5000000 rows)

Comment: autovacuum is on.  after an analyze, the row estimate is 1, cost is 59k. Running 
set enable_seqscan=off
still has it doing a seq scan

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us. It's hard to believe PostgreSQL 9.2 actually does a full table scan when doing a max() on the PK (see my link to explain.depesz.com).

Comment: See also here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/77e30/1

Comment: Hmm.  It was recently upgraded from 8.3.16 to 9.2.  Would that have any bearing?

Answer (score 6):

> except it needs to return 0 if there are no rows in the table

```
SELECT COALESCE(max(id), 0) FROM tbl;
```

This works because `max()` - like all aggregate functions - *always* returns a row, even if there are no rows in the table.
<sub>Fine point: this also returns `0` if all existing rows of `tbl` have `id IS NULL`.</sub>

See:

- [Return zero if no record is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839212/return-zero-if-no-record-is-found/17839278#17839278)

When *no row* can be returned, wrap the `SELECT` it in a subquery:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT max(id) FROM tbl), 0);  -- not necessary for max()
```

The key to performance is an **index** on `tbl.id` Could be a primary (or unique) key constraint, which is implemented using a unique index on the column. Or a plain b-tree index:

```
CREATE index foo on tbl(id)
```

See:

- [Return a value if no record is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098795/return-a-value-if-no-record-is-found/8098816#8098816)
- [How to display a default value when no match found in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200462/how-to-display-a-default-value-when-no-match-found-in-a-query/8200473#8200473)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
select
    case
        when (select id from tbl limit 1) is null then 0
        else (select id from tbl order by id desc limit 1)
    end;
```

Comment: `select count(1) from tbl` will cause full scan on the table resulting in VERY slow query.