# Return zero if no record is found

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, plpgsql, coalesce

I have a query inside a stored procedure that sums some values inside a table:

```
SELECT SUM(columnA) FROM my_table WHERE columnB = 1 INTO res;
```

After this select I subtract `res` value with an integer retrieved by another query and return the result. If `WHERE` clause is verified, all works fine. But if it's not, all my function returns is an empty column (maybe because I try to subtract a integer with an empty value).

How can I make my query return zero if the `WHERE` clause is not satisfied?

Comment: `INTO var` appended to `SELECT ...` is only valid in PL/pgSQL code, not in plain SQL. I assume this is part of a PL/pgSQL function or `DO` statement. Correct?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You could:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(columnA), 0) FROM my_table WHERE columnB = 1
INTO res;
```

This happens to work, because your query has an aggregate function and consequently *always* returns a row, even if nothing is found in the underlying table.

Plain queries without aggregate would return ***no row*** in such a case. `COALESCE` would never be called and couldn't save you. While dealing with a single column we can wrap the whole query instead:

```
SELECT COALESCE( (SELECT columnA FROM my_table WHERE ID = 1), 0)
INTO res;
```

Works for your original query as well:

```
SELECT COALESCE( (SELECT SUM(columnA) FROM my_table WHERE columnB = 1), 0)
INTO res;
```

More about [`COALESCE()` in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).
More about [aggregate functions in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html).
More **alternatives** in this later post:

- [How to return a value from a function if no value is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293018/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-function-if-no-value-is-found/29294021#29294021)

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: I think it should be noted that `COALESCE` is the *SQL standard* way to do it.

Comment: I had a [bad experience](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46486/function-hangs-with-null-case-operation) with `COALESCE`... Let's just say we're not friends anymore.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO It is more of `I had a bad experience with SQL Server` then `I had a bad experience with COALESCE`. There is nothing wrong with `COALESCE` in other RDBMS.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with postgresql, but in SQL Server or Oracle, using a subquery would work like below (in Oracle, the `SELECT 0` would be `SELECT 0 FROM DUAL`)

```
SELECT SUM(sub.value)
FROM
( 
  SELECT SUM(columnA) as value FROM my_table
  WHERE columnB = 1
  UNION
  SELECT 0 as value
) sub
```

Maybe this would work for postgresql too?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try: (I tried this and it worked for me)

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT SUM(columnA) FROM my_table WHERE columnB = 1),0)) INTO res;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` clause.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT  FROM my_table WHERE columnB = 1)
      THEN
         res := SUM(columnA);
      ELSE
         res := 0
      END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

[COALESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) should do the trick, for example :

```
(SELECT columnA from my_table where columnB=123) - 
COALESCE((SELECT SUM(columnA) FROM my_table WHERE columnB = 1 INTO res),0)
```

Here, if the second select query returns no rows, it defaults to 0.