# Running sums of item counts (given an inventory table of item population changes)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to figure out whether it is possible to easily derive running sums of item counts given a table that contains starting values and population differences or whether I should do it programmatically. Below's a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/):

We have a table where we track inventory category changes:

```
CREATE TABLE INVENTORY_MOVE (
n        INTEGER, -- time
product  VARCHAR, -- product code
countBef INTEGER, -- count of items for this product code before the inventory move
diff     INTEGER -- inventory difference
);


INSERT INTO INVENTORY_MOVE VALUES
(0, 'A'  , 0,  5), -- 5 As added in time '0',  total A: 5
(1, 'B'  , 0,  3), -- 3 Bs added in time '1',  total B: 3
(2, 'C'  , 0,  4),  --4 Cs added,  total C: 4
(3, 'C'  , 4,  2),  --2 Cs added,  total C: 6
(4, 'B'  , 3, -1),  --1 B removed, total B: 2
(5, 'A'  , 5, -3)   --3 A removed, total A: 2
```

The problem is now I am asked to produce running sums of arbitrary collections of product codes for a specific time window. E.g. what is the running sum of codes A and C in the time window [3, 5]? This should produce the following:

```
time | count-bef   | diff   | count-aft
---------------------------------------
3        9             2       11  -- in time '3' there were 5 As and 4 Cs (total: 9) and 2 more Cs were added
4        9             0       9   -- the inventory change in time '4' did not affect A or C counts
5       11            -3       8   -- in time '5' there were 5 As and 6 Cs (total: 11) and 3 As were removed
```

BTW, since the inventory change for time "4" did not result in any change in the quantities the query is supposed to report on, I'll accept answers where that row is missing, if that results in a simpler query.

Does it make sense to do the above in SQL or should I do it programmatically ?

Comment: What's the primary key of your table (or other unique indexes / constraints)?

Comment: As this is an SSCCE assume it is "n" which marks the time of the inventory change (assume time is logged with such accuracy that no two inventory events may coincide in time).

Comment: You display times 3,4,5 in the result. That does not match exact timestamps like you describe (timestamps with fractional digits cannot be (easily) enumerated sequentially). The accepted answer returns timestamps as found in the table, so there is no row for time `4`. The answer does not match the question. That would require a different query. Your demo should use the actual data types and the question should do the same with the rows you expect in the result.

Comment: It is true that the accepted answer does not return the row for time "4", however as I note in the comments the inventory change in time "4" did not affect the categories in question, so since no other answer was provided, I decided to accept it. I'll update the question to make that clear. My basic "issue" with the accepted answer is other (see my 2nd comment to it). About using the actual data types, this is an SSCCE so I wanted to keep things simple, the production system uses a multi-column business unique key plus a primary serial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem with the starting value efficiently:

```
SELECT im.n
     , row1.items + im.delta - im.diff AS count_bef
     , im.diff
     , row1.items + im.delta           AS count_aft
FROM  (
   SELECT COALESCE((
    SELECT sum(countBef + diff)::int
    FROM   inventory_move im 
    WHERE  product IN ('A', 'C')
    AND    n < 3
    AND    NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 FROM inventory_move
       WHERE  product = im.product
       AND    n < 3
       AND    n > im.n
       )
    ), 0) AS items
   ) row1
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT n, sum(diff) OVER (ORDER BY n)::int AS delta, diff
   FROM   inventory_move im 
   WHERE  product IN ('A', 'C')
   AND    n BETWEEN 3 AND 5   -- incl. both border
   ) im
ORDER  BY n;
```

#### Explain

- Assuming all columns to be `NOT NULL`, else additions can produce NULL.
  As later clarified `n` is unique.
  As also clarified we only need times with actual changes in the result (no `n = 4` in the example).
- In subquery `row1` calculate the sum of the latest values for given products **before the start** of your time frame.
- In subquery `im` calculate running sum of changes **since the start** of your time frame.
- In the outer SELECT add accordingly.
- `COALESCE` is only necessary if there can be *no rows* for the given products before your time frame. Details:

  - [Return zero if no record is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839212/return-zero-if-no-record-is-found/17839278#17839278)

Alternatively you could calculate the starting count of items like this:

```
SELECT sum(items) AS items
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (product)
          countBef + diff AS items
   FROM   inventory_move im 
   WHERE  product IN ('A', 'C')
   AND    n < 3
   ORDER  BY product, n DESC
   ) sub;
```

Test which is faster for you.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4de0c/34)

Answer (score 1):

Do the running total over all the data and then take the difference.  You can do this in a subquery by combining aggregation and window functions:

```
select im.*
from (select n,
             sum(sum(diff)) over (order by n) - sum(diff) as count_bef,
             sum(diff) as diff,
             sum(sum(diff)) over (order by n) as count_aft,        
      from INVENTORY_MOVE im
      where product in ('A', 'C')
      group by n
     ) im
where n between 3 and 5;
```

EDIT:

Hmmm, does this version work:

```
select im.*
from (select n,
             sum(diff) over (order by n) - diff as count_bef,
             diff,
             sum(diff) over (order by n) as count_aft
      from (select n, sum(diff) as diff
            from INVENTORY_MOVE im
            where product in ('A', 'C')
            group by n
           ) im
     ) im
where n between 3 and 5;
```

I may never have combined window functions and aggregation in Postgres, although it works in other databases.

Comment: after editing for what appeared to be some minor typos, I get: "column "im.diff" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: The only 'problem' that I see with this answer is that it does make use of the "countBef" values already present in the INVENTORY_MOVE table but instead reconstructs them by doing a SUM since the beginning of time. In a production system this would mean summing years of data when we just need the latest value before the period in question. Also, archiving past historical data would mess up the values the query computes.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus . . . I think there is a way around that, but I wasn't quite sure what the `countbef` was really doing.