# How to write an SQL query that returns count = 0 when no records found in group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a client table from which I need to select data in the following order:

```
Gender      Count
-----------------
Female      10
Male        50
Unknown     2
```

(The above table data is just as an example)

To achieve this, I used the following SQL:

```
SELECT decode(gender, 'F', 'Female', 'M', 'Male', 'Unknown') "Gender"
, count(ID) "Count"
FROM client c
WHERE c.created <= '01-JAN-2000'
GROUP BY decode(gender, 'F', 'Female', 'M', 'Male', 'Unknown')
ORDER BY decode(gender, 'F', 'Female', 'M', 'Male', 'Unknown')
;
```

But, the problem is there are not clients created before 1-JAN-2000! So, the table appears blank:

```
Gender     Count
----------------
```

But, I would like to show in this case like this:

```
Gender     Count
----------------
Female     0
Male       0
Unknown    0
```

Please tell how can I do that?

Comment: Count never returns NULL so you need to create a handle for when it is NULL

Comment: how? can you suggest? @AaronTroeger

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return zero if no record is found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839212/return-zero-if-no-record-is-found)

Comment: @sqluser No it's not.

Comment: if someone wants to find data that group count = 0, you can try to use not in,  that is first find data that count > 1, then use all data NOT IN cuont > 1 data, that is count 0 data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could start of with a select on the genders (using an inline view), then do a `left outer join` on the results. This will guarantee that there is always a list of genders available to show in the first column:

```
SELECT g.gender
,      count(ID) "Count"
FROM   ( select 'Female' gender from dual
         union all
         select 'Male' gender from dual
         union all
         select 'Unknown' gender from dual
       ) g
left
outer
join   client c
on     decode(c.gender, 'F', 'Female', 'M', 'Male', 'Unknown') = g.gender
and    c.created <= '01-JAN-2000'
GROUP
BY     g.gender
ORDER
BY     g.gender
;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should normalize your data to hold a gender table. Or at least use one (view) in your Query like below, and do a OUTER join.

And use standard date formats..

**EDIT:** For better readability and performance, you have to carefully categorize the gender. Here am presuming an additional category 'U' for unknown case.

```
SELECT  g.GENDER "Gender"
, count(ID) "Count"
FROM client c, 
     ( SELECT 'Female' As Gender,'F' as GenderId FROM DUAL
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Male','M' FROM DUAL
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Unknown','U' FROM DUAL
     ) g
WHERE c.created(+) <= DATE '2000-01-01'
    AND c.Gender(+) = g.genderId
GROUP BY g.gender
ORDER BY g.gender
;
```

Comment: This assumes gender will be U if it is not M or F.

Comment: It has to be fixed something, to be more proper.

Comment: It doesn't have to be fixed, as long as you move the `decode` to the `join`.

Comment: Proper I mean, the data,(ofcourse more efficient for querying) and yes, syntactically, it can be done pretty easily, as you showed.

Comment: this did not fix the problem ... this gives empty table as mine did... sorry

Comment: @SamiulAlHossaini updated query to add outer join to the constant as well

Comment: I wouldn't use the old outer join syntax anymore. It is hard to read and has some strange behaviour in more complex cases.

Comment: I rather feel `(+)` is comfortable! Perspective. And yes, agreed on the modern syntax's concept.

Comment: It does not run on my machine :( (at A Gender)

Comment: @SamiulAlHossaini it was a typo. It has to be 'As' .

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it

```
SELECT 
   'Female' Gender
   , Count(c.ID) Count
FROM 
   Client c
WHERE 
   c.Gender = 'F'

UNION ALL

SELECT 
   'Male' Gender
   , Count(c.ID) Count
FROM 
   Client c
WHERE 
   c.Gender = 'M'

UNION ALL

SELECT 
   'Unknown' Gender
   , Count(c.ID) Count
FROM 
   Client c
WHERE 
   c.Gender is NULL
```

Comment: Won't scale nice and is quite error prone if you change the select of the one, etc.

Comment: Won't scale nice? lol. It's nice and simple and is easy to read and modify, which perfectly caters to this customer's needs. It's certainly the easiest answer to read and understand so far. The most elegant looking too.

Comment: Trust me man, table name dont support `AS` for aliasing... in `Oracle` :)

Comment: Think about it Patrick. What are the chances that a new Gender is going to be introduced? This will be impemented as a stored procedure once, and there'd be no reason to ever change it again. No problem with keeping an open mind, but even if a new gender DID happen to emerge, it would just be a case of adding another block! Thanks for the extra laugh :) I was already appreciated the OP's original joke by including the Unknown results (as useful as they will additionally be).