# The meaning of return; without any value

Tags: java

i want to know the difference between the instruction `return;` and `return value;`, because when I use non void function my `return` instruction is followed by an expression, a value or a local variable containing a value.

Example:

```
public int f(a){a=1;return a},public int f(){return 0;}
```

But i don't understand a `return` followed just by a semi column without any value such as `return ;`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: javascript !== java

Comment: It stops execution of that method and returns back to the caller...

Comment: @AndrewLi I believe that question is *what* does it return back to the caller.

Comment: @TinyGiant In that case, nothing. To OP - The execution returns back to where the caller called it and continues on. Nothing is returned, execution just 'returns' back to where it began

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return zero if no record is found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839212/return-zero-if-no-record-is-found)

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand two things:

1. The `return` statement - this does two things a) it terminates the method's execution returning the point of execution to the statement just after where the method was called, b) it provides a way of returning a value (if the method does return a value)
2. A `void` method - the method does something but returns nothing

So a void method does not return anything so you just write `return;` to terminate. If say the method returned an `int` you would do something like `return 5;` or `return myInt;`.

Comment: Okay,if i've understood ,you mean return; is for void function?

Comment: @jochri3 no that's not it. return is for terminating the execution of a method and continue execution from where the method caller left off. That does not change for void or non-void methods. Where void vs. non-void differ is that non-void methods needs to return something and the way to specify what is returned is with the return statement. void methods dont return anything so you just write return; with no value. In fact if you have a void method that does not need to end early you can omit the return statement all together and just let the method go to the end.

Comment: @jochri3 are you satisfied with this answer?