# SQL Server 2008 help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm quite new to SQL and I'm stuck. I have the following query in SQL Server 2008 which works a treat, but I need to set the results for 'ErrorHandling' to show as 0 when a result of 1 is returned but leave any other results as they are (the results go into a webpage so can't have anything like 'null' or no results at all displayed).

```
USE IDS_Queues

SELECT FSState AS [hersham], COUNT(FSState) AS Totals
FROM hersham_idsinfo
WHERE (FSState = 'Loading') OR
      (FSState = N'Replicating') OR
      (FSState = N'ErrorHandling') OR
      (FSState = N'WaitingToReceiveMulticast')OR
      (FSState = N'GeneratingSubfiles')
GROUP BY FSState
```

This is the output format I need:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LOHD.jpg)

I've tried using `CASE` but can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Can you give us an example output with test data about what you are trying to do?

Comment: What exactly query using `case` you've tried? You haven't showed it in question - so it is hard to say what you've done wrong...

Comment: see this answers:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839212/return-zero-if-no-record-is-found

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to include "ErrorHandling" in the count? Please clarify?

Comment: Hi I need to inculde Error Handling, but as in the results screenshot (just edited post) when it returns '1' as the result - I need it do display '0' instead.

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` expression should work fine:

```
SELECT  [hersham],
        CASE 
            WHEN [hersham] = N'ErrorHandling' AND Totals = 1 THEN 0 
            ELSE Totals
        END Totals
FROM (  SELECT  FSState AS [hersham], 
                COUNT(FSState) AS Totals
        FROM hersham_idsinfo
        WHERE FSState IN (N'Loading',N'Replicating',N'ErrorHandling',
                          N'WaitingToReceiveMulticast',N'GeneratingSubfiles')) X
;
```