# Select default in case of no value returned

Tags: oracle, null, nvl

I am trying to get some default value in my resultset if query does not return anything. I am trying `nvl` for the same but it is not returning the expected default value. To simulate, Consider following query,

```
select nvl(null, '10') from dual where 1=0;
```

I want to get `10` in case of given condition is not true and query does not return any value. However above query not returning any row.

Comment: Check the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200462/how-to-display-a-default-value-when-no-match-found-in-a-query) , hope it helps.

Comment: @mohanrathour . . . `COALESCE()` versus `NVL()` has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 3):

Your query returns  zero rows. `NVL()` isn't going to change that **(*)**.

The correct solution is for the program which executes the query to handle NO_DATA_FOUND exception rather than fiddling the query.

However, you need  a workaround so here is one using two sub-queries, one for your actual query, one to for the default.

When `your_query` returns an empty set you get this:

```
SQL> with your_qry as
  2      ( select col1 from t42 where 1=0 )
  3     , dflt as
  4      ( select 10 as col1 from dual  )
  5  select col1
  6  from your_qry
  7  union all
  8  select col1
  9  from dflt
 10  where not exists (select * from your_qry );

      COL1
----------
        10
SQL>
```

And when it returns a row you get this:

```
SQL> with your_qry as
  2      ( select col1 from t42 )
  3     , dflt as
  4      ( select 10 as col1 from dual  )
  5  select col1
  6  from your_qry
  7  union all
  8  select col1
  9  from dflt
 10  where not exists (select * from your_qry );

      COL1
----------
        12
        13

SQL>
```

The WITH clause is optional here, it just makes it easier to write the query without duplication. This would have the same outcome:

```
select col1
from t42
where col0 is null
union all
select 10
from dual
where not exists (select col1 
                  from t42
                  where col0 is null)
;
```

---

**(*)** Okay, there are solutions which use `NVL()` or `COALESCE()` with aggregations to do this. They work with single column projections in a single row as this question poses, but break down when the real query has more than one row and/or more than one column. Aggregations change the results.

So this looks alright ...

```
SQL> with cte as (
  2      select 'Z' as col0, 12 as col1 from dual where 1=0 union all
  3     select 'X' as col0, 13 as col1 from dual where 1=0 )
  4  select
  5     nvl(max(col0), 'Y') as col0, nvl(max( col1), 10) as col1
  6  from cte;

COL0             COL1
---------- ----------
Y                  10

SQL>
```

... but this not so much:

```
SQL> with cte as (
  2      select 'Z' as col0, 12 as col1 from dual union all
  3     select 'X' as col0, 13 as col1 from dual )
  4  select
  5     nvl(max(col0), 'Y') as col0, nvl(max( col1), 10) as col1
  6  from cte;

COL0             COL1
---------- ----------
Z                  13

SQL>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can not handle NO_DATA_FOUND since I am appending this query as sub-query. Can you suggest any way to get the default value if no record found?

Comment: As it happens I was working on a kludge that used sub-queries, so maybe it will work for you.

Comment: Answer is correct but the approach of using `with` is not feasible in my case. The query I am looking for will be appended as sub-query in select clause of some other query.

Comment: Several people have invested their time to help you. I suggest you spend some​time yourself framing a decent question which explains what you have so far and what it is you want.

Comment: @Notabug -  simply googling `oracle with` and I think you understood what `with` means here.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this is what you need

You could change WHERE clause (in this case `WHERE COL > 1`) similarly in both places.

```
WITH T(COL) AS(
    SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 FROM DUAL  
)
 SELECT COL FROM T WHERE COL > 1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 10  AS COL FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM T WHERE COL > 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use aggregation.  An aggregation query always returns one row:

```
select coalesce(max(null), '10')
from dual
where 1 = 0;
```

I prefer `coalesce()` to `nvl()` because `coalesce()` is the ANSI standard function.  But, `nvl()` would work here just as well.

Comment: The OP is not using aggregation in their query; this would change the meaning of the query.

Comment: @MT0 . . . This is probably the simplest way to guarantee that exactly one row is returned from a query.  You don't seem to understand this.  I have used this technique multiple times in different databases when I need to ensure that one row is returned.

Comment: The OP wishes to return one row if "if query does not return anything" - they are not asking to return exactly one row, they want to return at least one row.

Comment: @MT0 . . . The query in the question returns at most one row, as does any query on `dual`.

Comment: This looks like answer I am looking for. but what is the difference max() making here?

Comment: The MAX() applies an aggregation to your your query. It guarantees one row is returned but, as the second part of my answer shows, it can change the non-default result set. So I could back to my recent point: you need to provide a realistic version of what you have and what you're expecting.