# Using variables in a PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, parameter-passing, naming-conventions, plpgsql, quotes

[Postgres PL/pgSQL docs say](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT):

> For any SQL command that does not return rows, for example `INSERT`
>   without a `RETURNING` clause, you can execute the command within a
>   PL/pgSQL function just by writing the command.
>
> Any PL/pgSQL variable name appearing in the command text is treated as
>   a parameter, and then the current value of the variable is provided as
>   the parameter value at run time.

But when I use variable names in my queries I get an error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "email"
> LINE 16: ...d,email,password) values(identity_id,current_ts,''email'',''...
> ```

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION app.create_identity(email varchar,passwd varchar)
RETURNS integer as $$
DECLARE
    current_ts          integer;
    new_identity_id     integer;
    int_max             integer;
    int_min             integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT extract(epoch FROM now())::integer INTO current_ts;
    int_min:=-2147483648;
    int_max:= 2147483647;
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            SELECT floor(int_min + (int_max - int_min + 1) * random()) INTO new_identity_id;
            IF new_identity_id != 0 THEN
                INSERT into app.identity(identity_id,date_inserted,email,password) values(identity_id,current_ts,''email'',''passwd'');
                RETURN new_identity_id;
            END IF;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN unique_violation THEN
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Why when I use variables in the query, Postgres throws an error. How is this supposed to be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@a_horse answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41367838/939860) your actual *question* and clarifies quoting issues and naming conflicts.

About quoting:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

About naming conflicts (behavior of plpgsql changed slightly over time):

- [Set a default return value for a Postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662731/set-a-default-return-value-for-a-postgres-function/7662787#7662787)
- [Postgres function returning a row as JSON value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142006/postgres-function-returning-a-row-as-json-value/31147662#31147662)

### Better solution

I suggest a completely different approach to begin with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION app.create_identity(_email text, _passwd text
                                             , OUT new_identity_id int) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _current_ts int := extract(epoch FROM now());
BEGIN
   LOOP
      --+ Generate compeltely random int4 numbers +-----------------------------
      -- integer (= int4) in Postgres is a signed integer occupying 4 bytes   --
      -- int4 ranges from -2147483648 to +2147483647, i.e. -2^31 to 2^31 - 1  --
      -- Multiply bigint 4294967296 (= 2^32) with random() (0.0 <= x < 1.0)   --
      --   trunc() the resulting (positive!) float8 - cheaper than floor()    -- 
      --   add result to -2147483648 and cast the next result back to int4    --
      -- The result fits the int4 range *exactly*                             --
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------
      INSERT INTO app.identity
            (identity_id, date_inserted,  email ,  password)
      SELECT _random_int, _current_ts  , _email , _passwd
      FROM  (SELECT (bigint '-2147483648'       -- could be int, but sum is bigint anyway
                   + bigint '4294967296' * random())::int) AS t(_random_int)  -- random int
      WHERE  _random_int <> 0                   -- exclude 0 (no insert)
      ON     CONFLICT (identity_id) DO NOTHING  -- no exception raised!
      RETURNING identity_id                     -- return *actually* inserted identity_id
      INTO   new_identity_id;                   -- OUT parameter, returned at end

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;                          -- exit after success
      -- maybe add counter and raise exception when exceeding n (100?) iterations
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Major points

- Your random integer calculation would result in an `integer out of range` **error**, because the intermediate term `int_max - int_min + 1` operates with `integer`, but the result won't fit.
  I suggest the cheaper, *correct* algorithm above.
- Entering a block with exception clause is considerably more expensive than without. Luckily, you do not actually need to raise an exception to begin with. Use an [UPSERT (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT), to solve this cheaply and elegantly (Postgres **9.5+**).
  [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

  > **Tip:** A block containing an `EXCEPTION` clause is significantly more
  >   expensive to enter and exit than a block without one. Therefore, don't
  >   use `EXCEPTION` without need.
- You don't need the extra `IF` construct either. Use `SELECT` with `WHERE`.
- Make `new_identity_id` an `OUT` parameter to simplify.
- Use the `RETURNING` clause and insert the *resulting* `identity_id` into the `OUT` parameter directly. Simpler code and faster execution aside, there is an additional, subtle benefit: you get the value that was *actually* inserted. If there are triggers or rules on the table, this might differ from what you sent with the `INSERT`.
- Assignments are relatively expensive in PL/pgSQL. Reduce those to a minimum for efficient code.
  You might remove the last remaining variable `_current_ts` as well, and do the calculation in the subquery, then you don't need a `DECLARE` at all. I left that one, since it might make sense to calculate it *once*, should the function loop multiple times ...
- All that remains is *one* SQL command, wrapped into a `LOOP` to retry until success.
- If there is a chance that your table might overflow (using all or most `int4` numbers) - and strictly speaking, there is *always* the *chance* - I would add a counter and raise an exception after maybe 100 iterations to avoid endless loops.

Comment: Wow! That's what I call engineering! I guess you are using single queries (all in one query) because after parsing they execute very fast. Have to upgrade my 9.4 installation now. Thanks!

Comment: @Nulik: Basically, yes. Behind the curtains, every assignment in plpgsql is a separate `SELECT` (very basic and fast, but still). Doing it all in a single query is typically faster, as long as it doesn't get complicated.

Answer (score 3):

You can not put the parameter names in single quotes (`''email''` and you can't use the parameter `email` "as is" because it has the same name as a column in the table. This name clash is one of the reasons it is highly recommended to **not** use variables or parameters that have the same name as a column in one of the tables. You have three choices to deal with this:

1. rename the variable. A common naming convention is to prefix parameters with `p_` e.g. `p_email`, then use the un-ambigous names in the `insert`

   ```
   INSERT into app.identity(identity_id,date_inserted,email,password) 
   values(identity_id,current_ts,p_email,p_password);
   ```
2. use the `$1` for the first parameter and `$2` for the second:

   ```
   INSERT into app.identity(identity_id,date_inserted,email,password) 
   values(identity_id,current_ts,$1,$2);
   ```
3. prefix the parameter name with the function name:

   ```
   INSERT into app.identity(identity_id,date_inserted,email,password) 
   values(identity_id,current_ts,create_identity.email,create_identity.password);
   ```

I would highly recommend to go with option 1

---

Unrelated, but: you don't need SELECT statements to assign variable values if you don't retrieve those values from a table.

```
SELECT extract(epoch FROM now())::integer INTO current_ts;
```

can be simplified to:

```
current_ts := extract(epoch FROM now())::integer;
```

and

```
SELECT floor(int_min + (int_max - int_min + 1) * random()) INTO new_identity_id;
```

to

```
new_identity_id := floor(int_min + (int_max - int_min + 1) * random());
```

Comment: it doesn't work!! I got inserted into the table the word 'email' but I wanted the value of the variable `email`

Comment: To make this easier to follow for future readers, it should probably be clarified in the first paragraph that what is actually wanted is *no* quote marks. If the parameter was `p_email`, you would *not* write it as `'p_email'`. It's not a question of dollar quoting and escapes, just a basic misunderstanding of how variables are interpreted.

Comment: @IMSoP: It's actually both, since the OP *also* misunderstood dollar-quoting. And there are several more misunderstandings ...